# Register pressure in Compute Shader

Tags: raytracing, performance, compute-shader, hlsl, memory

I'm in the process of writing a Ray Tracer using DirectCompute / HLSL. First, eye rays are generated (one per pixel). Then, rays are traced, shaded and reflected in a loop. Also, shadow rays for each light source are generated and tested for occlusion. As a scene structure, I'm using a KD Tree with Ropes$^1$.

I have analyzed the shader with Joshua Barczak's [Pyramid](https://github.com/jbarczak/Pyramid) and it seems that I have a major problem with register pressure, mainly vectors. On a Fiji GCN architecture, the shader uses 85 SGPRs and 81 VGPRs, limiting the number of simultaneous wavefronts per SIMD to 3 (VPGR).

Furthermore, I have implemented a simple counter in my shader, that atomically increases a value when a thread starts, decreases it when a thread ends and keeps track of the maximum number of shaders that were concurrently running. I've managed to get rid of some data and bring it up from 8192 to 9216, resulting in a correlated speedup of ~%13. When I use an empty dummy shader, I get 16384 concurrent threads.

I've tried to get rid of excessive variables, especially vectors, by keeping their lifetime as short as possible, and also tried storing some variables in groupshared memory and reading / writing directly from there, all without any change in register count whatsoever.

Are there any practical tips on how to take pressure of the registers? Is this even as much of a problem as I think it is?

I have also thought about splitting my Ray Tracer into various kernels. This should, the way I understand it, take pressure of the registers significantly, but also takes quite some coding effort on my part. Does this sound like an idea worth trying?

---

$^1$ [Popov et al.: Stackless KD-Tree Traversal for High Performance GPU Ray Tracing (2007).](https://graphics.cg.uni-saarland.de/fileadmin/cguds/papers/2007/popov_07_GPURT/Popov_et_al._-_Stackless_KD-Tree_Traversal_for_High_Performance_GPU_Ray_Tracing.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lowering register pressure doesn't necessarily give you any performance boost though. I recently went through this exercise myself on GCN architectures (for a simple ray tracer) and reduced register pressure so that it increased occupancy from 2 to 4, which had no impact on performance. It's generally a good idea to reduce the pressure if you need to hide memory latencies, but it really depends on what the real bottlenecks in your shaders are.

Since you are working on a GPU ray tracer, you might get better improvement in performance by paying attention to the divergence of threads and try to improve this instead. For example by trying to group rays based on location and direction to reduce divergence in KD-tree traversal per wave. I'm not familiar with the paper you are referring to, and you may already have considered this though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your interesting insights. Ropes++ is just way to traverse a kd tree without having to maintain a stack, so I have not paid attention to ray coherency so far.

Comment: Yeah, once you try to increase the ray coherency, it will likely mess up any earlier GPR optimizations you have done. I prefer to defer GPR optimizations to a later stage, though you still need to be aware of it earlier (e.g. to avoid algorithms with deep nested loops that tend to increase the pressure, etc.)